# Get DC++ hub information with python

Tags: python

Is there any way in which i can get a DC++ hub information like the online status of the hub, no. of users online, amount of data shared. I have access to the hubs, so that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own client (maybe using [some hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856786/proper-way-to-implement-a-direct-connect-client-in-twisted), the [ADC protocol](http://adc.sourceforge.net/) is not too complex) or reuse parts of [pyDC](http://pydc.sourceforge.net/).  Looks like all you want to do is connect to a hub, scrape some information, and drop off, so you don't need to handle searching or sharing.