# Direct connect (DC) library in python

Tags: python, networking, p2p

Is there any library available in Python to write direction connect (DC) clients? I was looking at the DC-clients and most of them are based on c, c++ and java and none ([barring a small implementation](http://pydc.sourceforge.net/)) in Python.

Comment: Not an fully answer but ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856786/proper-way-to-implement-a-direct-connect-client-in-twisted http://www.kristenwidman.com/blog/33/how-to-write-a-bittorrent-client-part-1/might http://www.kristenwidman.com/blog/71/how-to-write-a-bittorrent-client-part-2/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400828/how-to-write-a-simple-bittorrent-application might help